# How to display all object in array from local storage jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, cart

I made an array of objects holding data of cart items, Now after adding Items I want to display all data of items in shopping cart.
How can It be displayed ?
I dont know how to access properties in object and objects in array

```
var cartArray = []; //array of cart Items data
    var total = 0;
    var shipping = 2;

    $(".addToCart").click(function(){

               var flag = 0;
        //Get all data of item to be added
            var id= $(this).data("id");
            var price= $(this).data("price");
            var image = $(this).data('image');
            var name = $(this).data("name");
            var quantity = $(this).data("quantity");
            var availability = $(this).data("availability");
            var weight = $(this).data("weight");


            //check if cart is empty to remove empty cart view
               if( (cartArray.length === 0) ) { 
                $("#empty-cart").css("display","none");}

            //Traverse the cart list to check if item already exists or not
                 $.map(cartArray,function(item){
                 if (item.I == id){
                  item.Q++;
                  flag = 1;
                  console.log("each function runned,quantity increased");
                  console.log(item.Q);
                    return false;
                   }
                 })

          //Add new Item in cart
              if(flag == 0){
                  var itemObj ={
                    I : id,
                    IMG : image,
                    N : name,
                    W : weight,
                    A : availability,
                    P : price,
                    Q : quantity,
                  }
                     cartArray.push(itemObj);
                     localStorage.setItem('cartItem',JSON.stringify(cartArray)); 

                  var getItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItem'));  
});
```

Comment: post your sample json from local storage

Answer (score 0):

Here it is an example how to get the value from arrays and objects.

Also you can see in this url how arrays works:
[https://www.cpp.edu/~elab/ECE114/Array.html](https://www.cpp.edu/%7Eelab/ECE114/Array.html)

```js
let getItems = [2, 3, 7, {"key": "value"}];

//first value is array
getItems[0];
console.log(getItems[0]);

//second value is array
getItems[1];
console.log(getItems[1]);

//third value is array
getItems[2];
console.log(getItems[2]);

//fourth value which is object
getItems[3].key;
console.log(getItems[3].key);
```